# Can't get textbox value from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="dating.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <h2>
                        Skapa nytt konto
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Fyll i formulären nedan
                    </p>
                    <span class="failureNotification">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </span>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="RegisterUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                         ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                    <div class="accountInfo">
                        <fieldset class="register">
                            <legend>Kontoinformation</legend>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Användarnamn:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Du måste fylla i användarnamn" ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p class="submitButton">
                            <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" onclick="InsertUser" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Skapa användare" 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                </CustomNavigationTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

I'm trying to use the value from the textbox with ID UserName from code-behind, but this is not working:

```
UserName.Text
```

Comment: "but this is not working" is a terrible description. What isn't working? Errors? Exceptions? Something else?

Comment: What is  Skapa nytt konto

Fyll i formulären nedan
Kontoinformation

Användarnamn: * ? Please use english.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "this is not working"? Please give more detail on it.

Comment: you can use FindControl("UserName") or something likeTextBox userNameTextBox = (TextBox)RegisterUserWizardStep.Controls(0).FindControl("UserName");

Comment: Sorry for bad description, but I want the value from the textbox with ID UserName, but I can't find access to it from code-behind, and t doesn't work with using ID.Text

Comment: i fully understand that but basically it's impossible.

Comment: So to be simple, i cant give you any advice with that description of error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Findcontrol property not working in createUserWizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861442/findcontrol-property-not-working-in-createuserwizard)

Comment: Show us your code behind and where in the code your are trying to access the value because I can definitely access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the username by using `[ID of the CreateUserWizard].UserName`. The `CreateUserWizard` control exposes properties used to access values entered into the fields

```
 string username = RegisterUser.UserName;
 string email = RegisterUser.Email;
 ... etc
```

And you can also set it from code-behind

```
 RegisterUser.UserName = "John Doe";
```

### **Update: If you need to find the control, use**

```
TextBox usernameTextBox = RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;
string username = usernameTextBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

`TextBox UserName = (TextBox)"StepNameHere".FindControl("UserName");`

The control that you're accessing is currently not created on a event that you're using. I guess this will help.

Comment: Get nullreference exception by this, looks like it doesn't find the control UserName